# PHP - Header Location - redirect success login to member.php

Tags: php

I tried entering the header location as shown below but it does not redirect when the user successfully logs in. I have had success using this function when accessing the member.php page using the URL and it worked perfectly, redirected the user to the log in page.

I would like to know if there is something wrong with the code I have. Please do your part and guide me if ya can :) thank you!

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)

{

$connect = mysql_connect("", "", "") or die ("Couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("") or die("Couldn't find db");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);


}

?>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<html>

<div class="container">
    <div class="form_wrapper">

        <form action='login.php' method='POST'>
            <?php if ($numrows!=0)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $dbusername = $row ['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row ['password'];
    }
    // check to see if they match!
    if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
    {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        header ("Location: member.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
        echo "Incorrect password!";
}
else
    die("User does not exist!");
?>
<br><br>
            <input type='text' name='username' placeholder="Username"><br><br>
            <input type='password' name='password' placeholder="Password"><br><br>
            <input type='submit' value='Log In'>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: I've also tried it this way and it has failed. 

`header ("Location: http://example.com/member.php/");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch those 2 lines to start with:

```
    header ("Location: member.php");
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
```

To:

```
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    header ("Location: member.php");
```

Otherwise, you're moving away before the session is set.

Edit: Also make sure a php page that uses header('location... does not display any other text in the browser. It won't be able to change the header if there is some kind of output already.

Comment: I do have some text in the member.php page! Will that cause it to stop redirecting or maybe crash?

Comment: @Martin.html you have to have the header() before output to browser.

Comment: I assume the code you showed is in some kind of other file? Something like login.php maybe? And member.php is just the page you want to redirect to? In that case, there can't be any text output on login.php.

Comment: @Santy correct, this is the php from **login.php**. I updated the code above. Take a look :)

Comment: One more hint, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, always (at least) escape user input in SQL queries with (in your case) mysql_real_escape_string like so: `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);` It's also advisable to read up on mysqli instead of mysql ;)

Comment: @Santy I understand that my code isn't safe, I am really not worried about it because I'm learning how to create what I have in mind right now and when its successfully built, I'll work on that. Good catch tho!

Comment: 100% agreed with Santy about the `mysqli_*` functions and string escape. Also, in your code there is a lot of HTML output before calling the `header()` function. This is why it doesn't work (exactly like Santy said). Find a way (there are many) to move your username/password check above to where your query is. One approach is to output messages via variables.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Santy is right with switching to this:

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
header("Location: member.php");
```

But, also add this after header:

```
exit();
```

To stop PHP immediately and get out to your location.

Comment: True! Although it failed to redirect again.

Comment: @Martin.html Just like Santy said, if you already output something, it won't work. Use this code before outputting anything. In any case, I use `exit()` because if PHP keeps going on, it will output stuff and then fail redirection, but if the fact of outputting stuff was the actual error, then accept Santy's answer. All I can say now is you should check if your `member.php` file is actually checking for the `$_SESSION['username']` variable correctly, because if you have a redirection when the variable is not set, that is your real issue.

Comment: Yes, very brief. Thank you! I accepted his answer. :) I really am looking for more help though.